# Is the request made by the urllib.request module same as the requests made by Web browsers?

Tags: web, url, urllib3

Consider if I use the Python urllib.request module

```
import urllib.request 

request_url = urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.geeksforgeeks')
```

Is it the same request made by the web browser when I type a URL; from the server's point of view?

Comment: “Mostly” / “Effectively yes, except when it isn’t”. There may be some slight differences, such as User-Agent, or specific Content-Accept,  sent, eg. These _also_ vary between browsers though. Also, perhaps slight differences in protocol selection or even ciphers.. again, these also vary between browsers.

Comment: Is there a *specific case* where the behavior is observed to be *different*? That might be interesting to analyze..